# Why collectionView Cell not displaying data with no compilation error

Tags: swift5

hi I don't seem to find any error in below code.
problem: collectionView cell. not displaying data

please help to identify the problem.
Thanks

```
import UIKit

struct CustomData {
    var title: String
    var url: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
     let homeCellId = "cellId"
    
    let data = [
           CustomData(title: "Web", url: "abc.com/123"),
           CustomData(title: "Courses", url: "abc.com/courses"),
           CustomData(title: "Mobile", url: "abc.com/m/courses"),
       ]
    
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
            cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            cv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: homeCellId)
            return cv
        }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        //layout
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,constant: 80).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: homeCellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        
        cell.data = self.data[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var data: CustomData? {
        didSet {
            guard let data = data else { return }
        
            Title.text = data.title
            SubTitle.text = data.url
        }
    }

    lazy var Title: UILabel = {
        
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.text = "test"
        lbl.textColor = UIColor.black
        return lbl
    }()
    
    lazy var SubTitle: UILabel = {
        
        let lbl = UILabel()
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lbl.text = "test23"
        lbl.textColor = UIColor.black
        return lbl
    }()
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
       
        contentView.addSubview(Title)
        contentView.addSubview(SubTitle)
        
        
        Title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor,constant: 100).isActive = true
        Title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        SubTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: Title.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        SubTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the frame size and remove the constraint, it works.

```
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.view.bounds.size), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: homeCellId)
        return cv
    }()
```